# How to trace back the keys of a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop

I've created an ordered dictionary that helps to keep every combination of 2 elements multiplied by each other. The key stores the multiplication, and value stores the factors. 
So in my code below, od which is the ordered dictionary produces:

OrderedDict([(2, (2, 1)), (3, (3, 1)), (4, (2, 2)), (6, (3, 2))])

```
import collections

list = [2,3]
cost = 0.64
markup = 0.25

a = [(i*j) for i in list for j in range(1,3)] 
b = [(i, j) for i in list for j in range(1,3)] 

keys = a
values = b
d1 = dict(zip(keys, values))

od = collections.OrderedDict(sorted(d1.items())) # Ordered Dictionary

def profit_marg_calc(paid, free):  # Profit Margin Calculator
    total_cost = ((paid)+(free))*cost
    revenue = paid*2
    profit = revenue - total_cost
    profit_margin = profit/total_cost
    return profit_margin

print(max([profit_marg_calc(i,j) for i in od for j in od])) # Max Profit Margin

1.34375
```

When I calculate the max profit margin by passing in values from the ordered dictionary, how can I write a code to trace back the factors that gave 1.34375? Like how can I show it was a combination of say (2,1) (3,2) from the ordered dictionary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps:

```
print(max([(i,j) for i in od for j in od], 
          key=lambda args: profit_marg_calc(*args)))
```

Then you can just look up the values of the keys in the dictionary.

The key argument is a function that takes one argument, a tuple of two items, and applies that tuple to a function that takes two positional arguments, by using the splat operator to unpack the tuple's items as two positional arguments

Comment: could you explain what `key=lambda args: profit_marg_calc(*args)` does?